# External HDD disconnects (new cable)

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, external-disk, hdd

I use an external HDD to keep original raw photos. When I’m processing a large queue of photos, the HDD routinely disconnects. It may work for up to 20 minutes, then the volume is gone (in fact, sometimes the `/Volumes/foo` reference persists and I have to `rm` it by hand, otherwise the next time it’ll be creating copies as `/Volumes/foo 2`, etc., and my photo software will not find raw photos; but that’s another issue).

Symptoms:

- It happens more often especially if I’m exporting and simultaneously working on photos. Disconnections seem to correlate with times there are lots of reads and writes.
- I find the disconnects will happen more frequently over time as I’m working.

My setup:

1. A month old, brand new, almost empty LaCie 5TB external HDD (bought at official first-party Apple retail store)
2. A month old, brand new, fully intact Thunderbolt 3 USB-C 0.8m cable (bought at the same store)
3. An MBP M1, first generation, not super new but no other issues observed

What I tried:

- Different TB4 and TB3 USB-C cables (I have a few).
- Different LaCie HDD units (I have a couple).
- It does not matter if my MBP is connected to power or not, even if it’s the 140W charger.
- It doesn’t matter if my MBP is connected to a dock (CalDigit) that handles the HDD and also supplies power via a single cable.

I have resigned to the fact that it’ll just never work and be broken forever, so I am looking for causes and workarounds… E.g., is it the battery that can’t handle power draw? If power draw increases with reads/writes, could an intentionally slower cable help avoid disconnects at the cost of slower reads/writes? Is it still a problem on newer MBPs? Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: The CalDigit dock, is it connected to other peripherals?  Do they also get disconnected?   Can you also try a different external disk?  There's two possibilities here that need to be checked:  the USB port on the Mac and the external drive.

Comment: @Allan It doesn’t matter which of the two MBP ports is used, results are the same. And I wrote up front that I have two HDD units and this happens to both and regardless of whether the dock is involved. The dock is not connected to anything except HDD, laptop and power adapter. I can’t stress this enough, all units and cables are either new or (for MBP) in excellent condition, and I replaced everything except this MBP. (Similar happened to my older MBP and different dock and HDDs but I’ll keep it simple and focus on M1 one.)

Comment: I'm not referring to the *physical* port, but the port controller and associated electronic components (like a power rail).  It is totally possible that the USB controller or the power delivery circuitry,  both on the logic board, is faulty and needs to be repaired.  I was hoping that this wasn't the case but all signs are pointing to it as being the culprit.  There's one way to confirm and that's to connect the LaCies to another Mac and try transferring files.  If it does so without issue, you have a hardware problem.

Comment: I find it hard to believe because an older MBP had the same issue, though it was with another (some third party) dock and OEM HDDs in it. I would have to be very lucky to have it happen with every unit I get. But will assume it is a possibility, thanks. Perhaps we will see if anyone else has dealt with it, since I have seen similar complaints on Apple support forums it may be a common issue.

Comment: @Allan if we assume the problem is in fact involving  the power rail, would be happy to know whether there is a workaround that does not involve repairing/replacing the MBP (such as using a differently rated cable, even if slower). This could also help diagnose the issue without disassembly etc., if the problem goes away after this…

Comment: I can't say with any certainty without putting hands on.  I do know that USB requires a steady 5V reference and if that is being interrupted somehow, nothing will communicate.  Additionally, it could be a 3.3V or 1.5V rail that's affecting the chip itself, unfortunately, there's no test that can be run to  check that at our level.  Somone has to hook up diagnostic equipment.

Comment: Thank you, appreciated the pointers…